# Possible to leave recursion prematurely?

Tags: c++, recursion

My current recursive function works to a degree, but then ruins itself when it goes back down the stack.

```
void Graph::findPath( Room * curRoom )
{
if( curRoom -> myNumber == 0 )
{
    cout << "Outside.\n";
    //Escape the recursion!
}
else
{
    curRoom -> visited = true;

    if( curRoom -> North -> visited == false )
    {   

        escapePath[ _index ] = "North";
        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        ++_index;

        findPath( curRoom -> North );

        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        escapePath[ _index ] = "";
        --_index;
    }

    if( curRoom -> East -> visited == false )
    {   
        escapePath[ _index ] = "East";
        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        ++_index;

        findPath( curRoom -> East );

        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        escapePath[ _index ] = "";
        --_index;
    }

    if( curRoom -> South -> visited == false )
    {   
        escapePath[ _index ] = "South";
        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        ++_index;

        findPath( curRoom -> South );

        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        escapePath[ _index ] = "";
        --_index;
    }

    if( curRoom -> West -> visited == false )
    {   
        escapePath[ _index ] = "West";
        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        ++_index;

        findPath( curRoom -> West );

        cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
        escapePath[ _index ] = "";
        --_index;
    }
}
}
```

To save you some reading, the idea is that the base case is finding 0. Otherwise it tries four different cardinal directions, which is a different numbered room. Every time it makes a move, it adds the move it made to an external array, and every time it comes back up it removes that step from the stack.

My issue is that it has the correct path stored when it finds the 0, but removes it on the way back up.

Is there a way to escape it, such as a break.

No gotos or exceptions

Comment: You'll have to revise your logic. There's no way to `break` out of a recursive function, at least not in the same sense as with loops.

Comment: How about iterating over north/west/east/south (i.e. an array of ptr-to-member) instead of copy-pasting the same if-case four times?

Comment: Attn. answerers! Please limit your answer to one solution only, so that each answer can be discussed/voted on it's own. (Post several answers if you have more than solution. Currently there is much overlap)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a way to exit recursion using exceptions, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, modify your function to return a bool that indicates whether you've found 0 or not and modify your logic to return from the function without changing path if 0 has been found. Here's the illustration of the idea:

```
bool Graph::findPath( Room * curRoom )
{
    if( curRoom -> myNumber == 0 )
    {
        cout << "Outside.\n";
        //Escape the recursion!
        return true;
    }
    // ...
    if (findPath( curRoom -> North ))
        return true;
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely the correct answer.  You can keep track of a condition for multiple issues you may find, but never make "abort" one of those conditions.  To this extent booleans work perfectly for the abort while leaving the condition (usually an enum) alone to be checked at the end.  JUST REMEMBER TO ALWAYS CHECK on every recursive all.  That's the ONLY way the stack will unwind.

Comment: I know this is 12 years later, but I was looking back at my old questions and laughing at myself and saw this.

I used an exception to escape it and it was a class assignment. Met all the reqs but the prof failed the assignment because it was bullshit (we both know he's right, at the time I didn't) but he liked the ingenuity and gave me a couple days to fix it because of it.

Answer (score 0):

**exceptions** (or the C `longjmp`) are the way to leave a recursion. You might also have a `static boolean leaveme;` flag and start your function with `if (leaveme) return;` etc.

But `longjmp`  don't work nicely with destructors of values in local frames (while exceptions do).

Comment: -1 for longjmp, as it has no place in modern c++ code, and OP said no exceptions. Static/global flags are also not recommendable since they may cause threading or re-entrancy issues. (a similar flag in a some kind of"searchcontext" object used for each top-level call to findpath is ok though)

Comment: I did mention that longjmp don't work nicely with destructors!

Comment: Even though Basile talked about one of the foibles, this is a terrible solution because longjmp code is an absolute headache to debug.  In C code it's often required as an "exception substitute", but don't use this for recursion-exits.  Instead use an abort boolean, and always have the routine return that when done, as with @vitaut's answer.  This will unwind the stack fully, safely, and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `longjmp` and `setjmp` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csetjmp/ . But i do not think it is a good idea to use longjmp and setjmp in C++ .

Better is to set some special return value, which if detected by some depth will immediately return, like in C.

Or a global flag indicating the state of the recursion, if true we can do, else the recursion should return.

Answer (score 0):

At

`//Escape the recursion!`

I think you could just save a copy of the "answer" to a field outside your recursion. If the function is already modifying fields already outside the recursion, then perhaps make this a private helper function which contains an additional boolean parameter that flags whether you want to exit. The public function can simply call this one, to abstract away from having a flag like that in the parameters.

Something like:

```
void Graph::findPath( Room * curRoom, bool done )
```

---

```
//Escape the recursion!
done = true;
```

---

```
findPath( curRoom -> North );

if (done) // new line here
    return;

cout << "_index: " << _index << "\n";
escapePath[ _index ] = "";
--_index;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag = true;
int recursionFunction(parameters){
    if(flag){
        //do whatevere you wanna do

        if(condition satisfied){
            bool = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        return (whatever you want to return);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function returns an `int` but it has a code path with no `return` statement. This answer isn't useful in its current state.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.